# "Inheriting" operations in haskell data types

Tags: haskell

I have created the following type:

```hs
data Inch = Inch Double
instance Show Inch where
    show (Inch i) = show i ++ " inches"
```

Now, I'd like to be able to perform some mathematical operations on this type and, since the type itself is basically just a synonym with `Double` I was expecting to get them for free. However, this is not the case:

```hs
ghci> (3 :: Double) / 2
1.5
ghci> (3 :: Inch) / 2

<interactive>:74:2: error:
    • No instance for (Num Inch) arising from the literal ‘3’
    • In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(3 :: Inch)’
      In the expression: (3 :: Inch) / 2
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (3 :: Inch) / 2

<interactive>:74:13: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Inch) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the expression: (3 :: Inch) / 2
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (3 :: Inch) / 2
```

I think I can solve this by defining:

```hs
(/) :: Inch -> Double -> Inch
(Inch i) / n = Inch (i GHC.Real./ n)
```

This allows the previous code to run fine:

```hs
ghci> (Inch 3) / 2
1.5 inches
```

But I feel it's cumbersome and can't help thinking there surely must be a better way.
Is there?

Comment: Note that generally, if you write a type with only a single constructor and single field, you should usually make it a `newtype` instead of `data`, to avoid unnecessary pointers/thunks. (This makes no difference for my answer to the question.)

Comment: It's not quite a synonym, because it introduces an extra level of indirection: `Inch <loop>` and `<loop>` are distinguishable values, and that has operational consequences that could matter to the programmer. `newtype` is closer to being a synonym as it uses the same in-memory representation, but often the *reason* for making a new type is that existing behaviors don't make sense for your domain, so it would be unwise to make the compiler implicitly, automatically create behavior. You can explicitly ask to create behaviors using e.g. `deriving (Num, Fractional)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I wasn't aware of the performance implications, thank you!

Comment: @DanielWagner Good point. I mixed it up with `type` (which creates a type synonym).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.VectorSpace

data Length = Inches Double
  deriving (Generic, Show, AdditiveGroup, VectorSpace)
```

Then

```
ghci> Inches 3 ^/ 2
Inches 1.5
```

I'm using the [`^/` operator from the vector-space package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#v:-94--47-) because that actually has the suitable type `v -> Scalar v -> v`. By contrast, the standard [`/` from the `Fractional` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) has simply type `v -> v -> v`, which would be `Length -> Length -> Length` in this case, which does not make sense physically.

Comment: Being explicit with `DerivingStrategies`, what you have written is `data Length = Inches Double deriving stock (Generic, Show) deriving anyclass (AdditiveGroup, VectorSpace)`. The generic definition probably uses the behaviour of the underlying type making generalized newtype deriving a better candidate: `newtype Length = Inches Double deriving stock Show deriving newtype (AdditiveGroup, VectorSpace)`. That way we don't need the generic representation and the methods are guaranteed to be zero cost.

Comment: @Iceland_jack That comment makes me wonder: does GHC have a way of reporting which strategy it used to resolve a `deriving` request? One of the `-ddump` flags, perhaps? A quick look through the docs shows `-ddump-deriv`, but that seems to print the code generated, not which generator was used, and it's not obvious to me that you can always uniquely identify the generator from the resulting code... or can you?

Comment: It is actually tricky to identify, when I was going through the ghc base and making deriving strategies explicit I often got it wrong. The rules to determine which are unnecessarily complicated and I don't think there is any way to get ghc to report them. But you are able to infer them from the output: `stock` is the only strategy that produces an actual implementation. `anyclass` simply obmits the class body and looks like `instance AdditiveGroup Length where`. `newtype` and `via` produce one `coerce` per method, you can't distinguish them from the output alone but `via` must be explicit

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler that `Inch` is a number by making it an instance of some suitable class.  One option is the `Num` class:

```
> :info Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
  {-# MINIMAL (+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-)) #-}
```

Now we define `Inch`.  I'll use a `newtype` instead of `data` so we can use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to implement the `Num` instance more easily:

```
> :set -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
> newtype Inch = Inch Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Num)
> Inch 3 + Inch 5
Inch 8
```

It is worth noting that Inch is actually not a number - if you try `Inch 4 / Inch 2` you get `Inch 2`, but to be correct the units should cancel out, leaving a unitless `2`.  But how to deal with that is beyond the scope of this answer, in which I pedantically uses more old fashioned constructs

Comment: Interesting! So, by just adding a constructor (`Inch Int` in your example) I am not telling the compiler that `Inch` should do whatever `Int` should do! That was my (clearly wrong) assumption before seeing your and @leftaroundabout's answers. Coming from non-FP languages I'd assumed that adding a constructor would sort of be the same as "inheriting from a class" in an OOP language.

Comment: I'm also intrigued at the problem your hinting at. In fact, the next step in my toy project is to compute the area, which, as you have already pointed out, won't give me "SquaredInch" as a result. Stay tuned - I'm going to raise another question then!

Comment: I was indeed about to raise another question but the answer (well, one answer, at least) was only a couple of clicks away: https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/131/type-safe-dimensional-analysis-in-haskell . @David was it this you had in mind?

Comment: Yes that is the kind of thing I was thinking about, but I thought it would be helpful to get there in steps. When you create `newtype Inch` you are indeed creating a wholly new type  with, initially, no behaviors.  You get to create the instances that define everything about its behavior.  Did you find this answer useful?

Comment: Yes, very much so. I've also opened [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73390539/222529), spurred by your comment, but it looks like it's way out of my league for now.