# Modelling the composition of units (e.g. Inch, Dollar, etc) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

Following up from [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73375273/222529), where I asked how I could create a type that would model a unit (e.g. `Inch`) as a type in Haskell, I now face the problem of how to perform operations on that and other units and mix them correctly.

For instance, given:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.VectorSpace

newtype Inch = Inch Double
  deriving (Generic, Show, AdditiveGroup, VectorSpace)
```

How can I define a function to compute the area with the following signature?

```hs
circleArea :: Inch -> SquareInch
```

And how about the "price area ratio" (say, dollars per inch^2)?

```hs
priceAreaRatio :: Inch -> Price -> PricePerSquareInch
```

Those signatures seem wrong: how can I express that `SquareInch` is actually `Inch * Inch`? And that the `PricePerSquareInch` really is `Price / (Inch * Inch)`?

I have found a [potential solution here](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/131/type-safe-dimensional-analysis-in-haskell) but I am not well-versed in Haskell enough to understand whether that is just a toy solution, an experiment, or really a good practice.

How can I model my problem?

Comment: Check out https://hackage.haskell.org/package/units

Comment: Haskell has already packages to let the type system validate dimensions. For example https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/units

Comment: Awesome, thank you both - I think I've got enough material to go on now.

Comment: FWIW, doing what you want is not easy. Even using an existing package, you may find yourself wrangling with some intense type-level features, especially if you want to add your own units (this was my experience). Since it sounds like you're a beginner to Haskell, I would take caution jumping into such advanced stuff. I mean, don't let me discourage you, but also don't feel ashamed to just use `Double` for everything to start yourself off, if that's what will work best for you!

Comment: @Quelklef good shout indeed. Using native types (e.g. `Double`) for everything is effectively what I have done as a first approximation - and basically the approach I'd follow in another language with a less powerful type system. On the other hand, I'm trying to understand where all this "Haskell power" really comes from, and I must admit, the whole process is a bit daunting as a beginner: either I code as I code in other languages or I'm stuck because things get too hairy.

Comment: The `SquaredInch` approach is actually a pretty good way to ease into this.   Don't create the `Num` instance I described in your other post, handcraft the operations you need with custom types as necessary.   That is, if just using `Double` everywhere becomes too confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me give this opinion: IMO the type should be called `Length`, not `Inch`. The *constructor* should be called `Inches`, but the beauty of representing physical quantities with types is that the unit really becomes an “invisible” implementation detail. You could in fact use `-XPatternSynonyms` to work with different constructors for different units of the same length type, and/or lens-isomorphism for unit conversion. But this is somewhat tangential to the question.

The comments have already linked to existing physical-units libraries. Using one of those would definitely be the most sensible approach for a real project.

Stephan Boyer's blog post you've linked is definitely intriguing, however representing dimension-quotiens by general functions is really *not* very practical.

I'll show something in between: still using bespoke types instead of bell&whistley physical-unit ones, but anyway within a more numerics-suitable framework.

Already in your previous question, I pointed to the [vector-space library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space), because `VectorSpace` (unlike `Num`) is a suitable abstraction for physical quantities. As you've noticed, it only supports addition and scaling-by-real-number though, not multiplying or dividing physical quantities.

But the mathematical concept of vector spaces does extend to such operations as well. The Boyer blog goes in this direction: it represents `m/s` by a *function* `Time -> Length`. Which does make sense: what is a velocity? It's something that tells you, “if you wait for so and so long, how long will the object travel”.

However, `Time -> Length` is a way too *big* type, both in the sense that storing an arbitrary function is total overkill and inefficient for something that you know can also be represented by a single number, but more importantly also in that it doesn't capture the fundamental idea: a velocity is by definition a *linearized* function `Time -> Length`, because for sufficiently small time-deltas the motion can always be approximated by the first two Taylor terms.
And it is well known that linear functions are sensibly described as *matrices*<sup>†</sup>. In our case, both time and length is a 1-dimensional space, so it'll be a 1×1 matrix... IOW a single number again.

This idea of abstracting over linear functions in a type-safe manner but still having numbers/matrices as the internal representation is what I wrote the [linearmap-category package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.4.2.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html) for. It builds upon `vector-space`, but the classes turn out to become a lot uglier. Fortunately, for a simple type like yours the instances can be auto-generated: first you use `-XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` for making instances of the `vector-space` classes, then there's a Template Haskell macro for also defining the linear-map etc. types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, UndecidableInstances, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Math.LinearMap.Category
import Math.LinearMap.Category.Instances.Deriving
import Data.VectorSpace
import Data.Basis

newtype Length = Inches Double deriving (Show, AdditiveGroup, VectorSpace, HasBasis)
makeLinearSpaceFromBasis [t| Length |]

newtype Price = Euros Double deriving (Show, AdditiveGroup, VectorSpace, HasBasis)
makeLinearSpaceFromBasis [t| Price |]
```

Now you can use the type combinators from `linearmap-category`, and always immediately have the vector space operations on them! As I already said, quotients correspond to linear maps. Products correspond to [tensor products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), which again is for the 1-dimensional case also just a newtype wrapper around a single number.

```
type Area = Length ⊗ Length

type PricePerArea = Area +> Price

circleArea :: Length -> Area
circleArea r = (4*pi)*^(r⊗r)
```

It's not really clear to me what you want the `priceAreaRatio` function to do, but this would probably be implemented with [`-+|>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.4.2.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html#v:-45--43--124--62-).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually though, matrices are also often not a good representation, because they scale quadratically in the dimension of the spaces. Of course this is not relevant here.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @leftaraoundabout! I admit it took me a good few hours to understand the whole answer. Thanks for explaining why the type constructor should be named `Length` and value constructor `Inches`. It definitely makes sense. The reason why I went for the same name is because I blindly followed an [advice in the book "Real World Haskell"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nh0okI1a1sQC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq="Not+only+is+it+legal").

Comment: As for the rest, really great explanation. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer!